# play sound if object is detected

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame

I'm working on an object detection model using raspberry Pi. I've used Google's Object Detection API to detect models, My question is how to play sound when an object of a specific class(say human (i.e 'id' : 22))is detected.

I've tried a little and the code I came to is this,

```
if 22 in classes:
    threading.Thread(play_sound()).start()
def play_sound():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(1,0.0)
    pygame.time.wait(5000)
    pygame.mixer.stop()
```

In this code, the problem I'm getting is

1. Sound starts playing even before the object is detected, I tried debugging but don't know why.
2. I'm starting the same thread again
3. If I use different threads, the pi runs out of resources and the whole execution stops

Is there any way to get this to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `object-detection` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: As an orthogonal issue, I'd suggest that you move the `pygame.init()` and `pygame.mixes.music.load(...)` out of `play_sound()`. Do not mix building and running.

Comment: Well, have you checked your 'classes' variable? Does it maybe always contain 22?

Comment: @G.Brown no it doesn't always contain "22", it only contains "22" when it detects a human

Comment: So this has eventually got nothing to do with sound playing, right? You could as well just `print("Human in sight")` in the reaction and still see the problem. Correct?

Comment: The thing is, it works correctly without a thread, it only plays sound or prints "human in sight" when it is in the main thread itself. But to play sound simultaneously while detecting, I need a thread. This is what my problem is

Comment: So perhaps, this question could be updated with a sound-free and object-detection-free MWE? Additionally, can you give us an approximate figure of the time difference between the trigger (spotting the human) and reaction (playing the sound)?

Comment: Okay the time difference between the detection and code must be less than a second because the camera captures and process a frame per second. The reason why I need a thread is I have to play a sound of 5 second duration. If I play it in the main thread, it'll wait in the same line for five seconds to let the sound play out, which causes a problem because the detection is stopped

Comment: I think dedObed was asking what the current time difference is, not the desired/expected time difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use threads (you don't need them), don't use `pygame.time.wait`, and don't use `pygame.mixer.music` if you don't want to use it for background music.

Use a [`Sound` object](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) (and maybe provide a `maxtime` if you want to it's [`play`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play) function).

So your code should look more like this:

```
pygame.init()
detected_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('filename')

...
    if 22 in classes:
        # use loops=-1 if the sound's length is less than 5 seconds
        # so it's repeated until we hit the maxtime of 5000ms
        detected_sound.play(loops=-1, maxtime=5000)
...
```